# PHP split a string containing two words

Tags: php

Like "Multi thinker" its a string... in php how i can split it that multi shows in left and thinker shows in right like

**MULTI**                                                                                                                                                                                 **Thinker**

i will create a user input name whatever he input 'full name' will split like above.

here is the code i try

```
    <?php

      $name = $_POST['name'];

     echo str_replace(" ","\t \t",$name);
   ?>
```

here i used str_replace i already tried preg and ereg replace but it doesnt meet my requirement.

Comment: This is more a HTML than PHP issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$name = 'Multi thinker';
$data = explode(' ',$name);
echo '<div>
      <div style="float:left">'.$data[0].'</div>
      <div style="float:right">'.$data[1].'</div>
      </div>';
```